# Computed filtering not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So,I'm giving me first proper look at Vue.js since 2.0. And I'm having a hard time going from `filter` to `computed`.

Here is where I'm at (using `vue-resource` for the API call):

```
var moviesURL = 'http://localhost/api/movies';

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    liveFilter: '',
    movies: ''
  },

  methods: {
    getMovies: function() {
      this.$http.get(moviesURL).then(response => {
        this.movies = response.body;
      }, response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
    }
  },

  computed: {
    filteredMovies: function() {
      var self = this
      return this.movies.filter(function(movie) {
        return movie.indexOf(self.liveFilter) !== -1
      });
    }
  },

  created: function() {
    this.getMovies();
  }
});
```

And I keep getting those errors:

[image]

And I can't really my finger on what I'm doing wrong... Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot filter over string. In your data `movies` should be an empty array, not empty string.

Also, be sure that `response.body` is an array too.

Comment: Oh, I did not know initialization was important even when you reasign it after, thanks. But know, it's blocking on `return movie.indexOf` as if movie was not an array... But `{{ movie.title[0].value }}` works in the HTML, so, it is, isn't it?

Comment: `indexOf` is working just fine only for arrays of primitive values, eg `['filter', 'filter2']`, I assume your movies array is a collection of objects, not primitive values, maybe you can use lodash (or undescore) to filter based on object attribute https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter

Comment: But, you can just write something like ```return this.movies.filter(function(movie) {
        return movie.title == self.liveFilter
      });``` But keep in mind that it's exact comparasion ;) Maybe regexp will help here. Btw - why title is an array?

Comment: I guess if I want to mimic the old filterBy, I'll really have to use external libraries... That's a bit sad... But thank you :) (and title is in an array because I'm calling an API built by Drupal and, that how it does it, sadly... )

Answer (score 1):

You initiate the movies as an empty string, and  a string doesn't have a .find() method. Use an empty array instead

Comment: Oh, I did not know initialization was important even when you reasign it after, thanks. But know, it's blocking on `return movie.indexOf` as if movie was not an array... But `{{ movie.title[0].value }}` works in the HTML, so, it is, isn't it?

Comment: Your ajax request is asynchronous, so your component renders without any of that data in the first run. That's where the error happens. After the data has been received, the component can re-render, and create all HTML just fine.